# Java APIs or Web services to format (or beautify) the html, xml, .java files

Tags: java, solr, formatting, pretty-print

Are there any Java APIs (or web services) to beautify/format/pretty-print the html, xml and .java source code files?

So basically, I m indexing these various types of files in Apache Solr server and then fetching it when user searches for it. I m using Solr Cell for this. (Its like a grepcode application.)

The problem here is the file content comes as a plain text w/o any formatting (as the Solr field type is 'text' in the schema).

I m looking for any APIs (in Java) or web services so that I can hook it up in my application and convert the text (String in Java) to well formatted output to show on a web page.

Appreciate the pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: Solr uses Apache Tika for extracting documents. Try to integrate into a java project

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out. Its completely new for me.. Do you recommend any link/s to go over?

Comment: hey Apache Tika is to extract the metadata info from various file formats and parse it into a String. This is what I m doing in Solr (with Solr Cell).  My question is how to convert this String back to its original format ?? I need some kind reverse process here, that will convert the String to html,xml format.

Comment: please search around on how to convert stuff into (simplified) HTML using Tika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution html  and  tag is doing the trick.
All I wanted was to preserve the whitespaces while displaying the content (string).

Thanks.